# cout - what it stands for?

Tags: c++, cout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the “c” mean in cout, cin, cerr and clog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262232/what-does-the-c-mean-in-cout-cin-cerr-and-clog)

Can someone please explain to me what cout stands for?

Comment: Freedom, Apple Pie, and The American Way.

Comment: Using streams for input formatting is a peccadillo since real men write their own parsers. Hence the input stream was originally called `sin`, but this conflicted with the *stable isomorphic numerator* in BCPL. So Stroustrup reluctantly changed the name to `cin`. Thus when he needed a name for the output formatting stream, he decided to call it `cout`. That joker.

Comment: @casablanca I don't 100% agree with your comment because I'm an example of a random user who googled this question and finally found the correct answer here.

Answer (score 28):

The "c" stands for [character](//www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#cout). By default, most systems have their standard output set to the console, where text messages are shown, although this can generally be redirected. The "c" is sometimes mistakenly attributed as "console."

The "out" stands for output

Comment: According to Bjarne Stroustrup: The "c" stands for "character" - http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#cout

Comment: @ Michael, beat ya to the punch :p

Comment: bjarne says " The "c" stands for "character" because iostreams map values to and from byte (char) representations."

Comment: "beat ya to the punch" -- um, no. Your answer says that the "c" stands for "console", which is blatantly wrong. Saying that it "also" stands for "character" is nonsense -- it *only* stands for "character".

Comment: Thanks for the mature response and correction. I apologize for the unnecessary harshness of my previous comment.

Answer (score -7):

I'll hazard a guess...

Channel Out

Comment: In my defence, the book I have (Josuttis) refers to cout as "the standard output channel"

Comment: Throw out that book. cout stands for console or character output, which is by default is directed to standard output.

Comment: StackOverflow is for answers, not guesses. The "c" stands for "character" (and not "console").

Comment: let's throw google away too. I asked "why is cout called cout" and it returned `The identifier cout stands for common output`.

Comment: @JimBalter Why "Console" is false?

Comment: It's false because it's not true. The 'c' stands for 'character'. See , e.g., https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/library-function/iostream/cout

Comment: "let's throw google away too" No, let's not. "it returned The identifier cout stands for common output" -- Google returns references, not answers. No reliable reference says "common" ... they all say "character", which is correct.